# Event Listener for RDFa attribute

Tags: javascript, html, listener, rdfa

Are there any ways to implement the event-listener mechanism for all RDFa attributes in a specific HTML page ?

That is, when I click on a word/sentence, if this text belongs to some RDFa attributes embedded in the HTML page, a javascript function will be called ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Firefox plugin which does exactly this:

- [Semantic Radar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/semantic-radar/)

[Hack the XPI](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility) and look for the corresponding JavaScript, or join the [dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/sioc-dev).